# Auto generated columns within WordPress are splitting content in the middle of HTML?

Tags: php, html, image, wordpress, multiple-columns

I'm using the following function to automatically output the content from a WordPress post in to 3 columns. However, when minimal content with an image is added to the post, the function splits the content for another column in the middle of the img tag HTML, breaking the image and content.

Any idea how to resolve this?

```
function content_split($text, $separator = '<hr/>', $start = false ) {

if ( $start === false) {
    $string = '';
    $start = ceil(strlen($text) / 3);

    $string.= substr($text,0,$start);
    $string.= $separator;
    $string.= substr($text,$start,$start);
    $string.= $separator;
    $string.= substr($text,($start*2),$start);

    return $string;
}

$lastSpace = false;
$split = substr($text, 0, $start - 1);

// if the text is split at a good breaking point already.
if (in_array(substr($text, $start - 1, 1), array(' ', '.', '!', '?'))) {

$split .= substr($text, $start, 1);
// Calculate when we should start the split
$trueStart = strlen($split);

// find a good point to break the text.
} else {

$split = substr($split, 0, $start - strlen($separator));
$lastSpace = strrpos($split, ' ');

if ($lastSpace !== false) {
$split = substr($split, 0, $lastSpace);
}
if (in_array(substr($split, -1, 1), array(','))) {
$split = substr($split, 0, -1);
}

// Calculate when we should start the split
$trueStart = strlen($split);
}
//now we know when to split the text
return substr_replace($text, $separator, $trueStart, 0);

}
```